# Strange behavior of boost::multiprecision::pow when handling zero values with big reals

Tags: c++, boost, g++

I have the following code:

```
boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100 frn = 
    boost::multiprecision::pow(boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100(0),
      boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100(2));
std::cout << "Trial1: " << frn << std::endl;

frn = boost::multiprecision::pow(boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100(2),
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100(0));
std::cout << "Trial2: " << frn << std::endl;  

frn = boost::multiprecision::pow(boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100(2),
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100(2));
std::cout << "Trial3: " << frn << std::endl;

frn = boost::multiprecision::pow(boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100(2),
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100(3));
std::cout << "Trial4: " << frn << std::endl;

frn = boost::multiprecision::pow(boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100(2),
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100(4));
std::cout << "Trial5: " << frn << std::endl;

frn = boost::multiprecision::pow(boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100(2),
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100(5));
std::cout << "Trial6: " << frn << std::endl;
```

Of course I have included libraries and all. I just showed a fragment in the main procedure.

I get this output:

```
Trial1: 1
Trial2: 1
Trial3: 4
Trial4: 8
Trial5: 16
Trial6: 32
```

The problem is in the first value. I am asking for 0 raised to 2 but I get 1 instead of 0 (as if I were trying to get 2 raised to 0). I thought arguments were inverted so I tried inverting them but still got 1. I thought the procedure was broken somehow and get other values but it seems working well with values different from zero.

What's happening??? Thankyou

Comment: Only first answer is incorrect, second is right, since any number ^ 0 == 1.

Comment: Yeah, sorry a typing mistake, fixing it